# Selenium fails to get Alt Attribute of the first image on a result page

Tags: python, selenium

Selenium fails to get Attribute of an image, that I am getting with below method (class name). What am I doing wrong? This is happening on the Amazon HP.

```
def getByClass(InputElement, amazonDriver):
    getByClass = WebDriverWait(amazonDriver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, InputElement)))
    return getByClass
```

Now I call this like this:

```
amazonResultImage = getByClass('s-image', amazonDriver)
assert 'George Duke' in amazonResultImage.get_attribute("alt")
```

Now I get this error message:

```
  File "./amazon.py", line 23, in <module>
    assert 'Dream on by George Duke (2011-11-22)' in amazonResultImage.get_attribute("alt")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 143, in get_attribute
    resp = self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTE, {'name': name})
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/31W0bbjFwJL._AC_UY218_ML3_.jpg" class="s-image" alt="Sheila E. &amp; George Duke - A Love Bizarre / I Want You For Myself - Ballroom Records" srcset="" data-image-index="2" data-image-load="" data-image-latency="s-product-image" data-image-source-density="1">
```

Comment: Are you getting the error message on `get_attribute("href")` or `get_attribute("alt")`? The code you posted shows that you are getting the `href` attribute, but the error message you posted is showing an error on `alt`. I'm confused about which code from your sample is running here.

Comment: No its a typo. As a matter of fact the error is exactly same for whatever attribute you request.

Comment: To figure out why the assertion is failing, you could try `alt_attribute = amazonResultImage.get_attribute("alt")` followed by `print(alt_attribute)` to see what's being fetched. Depending on the results of the `print`, we can go from there.

Comment: Been there tried that, same error.

Comment: Same assertion error when running a `print(text)` statement? It wouldn't make sense if you were receiving an `assert` error message when you are just trying to print something. Is nothing printing out at all, and you are hitting an exception when calling this? You can also try `print(amazonResultImage)` to see if any WebElement is being located at all.

Comment: instead of print I let the machine verify. The point is that the get_attrbitue does not work. Neither the assertion nor the print create any problems for me.

Comment: Check if there's more than one element with class `s-image`

Comment: If `get_attribute` is specifically what's causing problems here, you should probably post the HTML for the web element you are trying to locate. There's not much more troubleshooting we can do without any HTML to reference.

Comment: I think Sers is onto something, but there aren't many of these classname occurences, only one, somehow the underlying expected condition I am using seems to work in an inconsistent fashion. So clicking on the element works with .click(), but getting the attribute not, same object. I also attached the HTML as requested.

Comment: Please share `amazonResultImage.get_attribute("alt")` value before `assert`. Is it empty?

Comment: Now its working after I commented out this line: `amazonResultImage.click()` and the `print()` is printing out the Title as expected. Why should a click on the WebElement alter the Element itself?

Comment: Why is the object destroyed after clicking on it?

Comment: @meshfields to answer your above question, clicking on an element probably triggers some `onclick()` event that updates the WebElement properties. This is a common issue that many selenium users run into. Your element hasn't been 'destroyed', but it has gone stale. You have a reference to a WebElement that is no longer in its original state. You will have to call `driver.find_element` on the element once more to get a 'fresh' one.

Comment: Browse to the page in Chrome, open the devtools, and run `$$(".s-image")`. How many elements are found? My guess is more than one. It's likely the element you want is not the first element found with that locator. We're going to need more of the relevant HTML around that element and a link to the page would be really helpful also.